# Can I use nuget packages which is not written OS ver 32 or 64 for 32 and 64 bit OS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, 32bit-64bit

Now I got several nuget packages(.nupkg) and installed VS's project on 64bit OS.
It was successfully finished.
And I'd like to install these packages to 32bit PC(StandAlone) by using CD which is burned .nupkg files.
(This PC cannot connect to Internet)
These packages seems to be not defined OS version specifically.
I have a quetion which is written in above title.
Can I use nuget packages which is not written OS ver 32 or 64 for 32 and 64 bit OS? 
And would you give me some reaseons about your answer.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet packages do not distinguish between 32 or 64-bit version of OS. They can be installed to both.

There was an issue filed on codeplex to support distinguishing for different platforms as

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/679